# Using Html DOM in firefox plug-in?

Tags: firefox-addon, google-chrome-extension

Can you use Html DOM in firefox plug in to...

1) write/Auto fill in a form?

2) Read values in label? Textboxes? And use them in your program?

Comment: I don't get, how Chrome/Firefox are related here? However, it is possible, check out IMacros for Firefox.

Comment: Your title says Firefox Plugin, but your question says Chrome Extension.  Can you clarify?

Comment: The OP created the same question for chrome. Copy&Paste error. I don't think that it is necessary to create to different questions for this.

Comment: @Felix, since you edited the tags, could you edit the Chrome to Firefox?

Comment: Sorry guys, fixedfelix is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Firefox, the current document is accessible in JavaScript by `content.document` and from there you can do anything you would do in JavaScript on the page itself.

Comment: JavaScript is typically what is used for Firefox extensions (as well as XUL and CSS of course). If you want to use Java instead, you can do that, although I'm not sure if there's any advantage to doing so in this case. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Java_in_Firefox_Extensions